# Firebase signInWithPopup doesn't work with Firefox - reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to use firebase to create a login / user registration module.
I use the function signInWithPopup (provider) which works perfectly on chrome
however on firefox, the popup does not appear, a new tab opens but that's all, no connection / registration possible.

This is my code:

```
signInWithPopup(provider) 
.then((result) => {
  console.log(result);
  const user = result.user;
  this.setState({
    user
  });
  window.location.href ="/HomeUser";
});
```

Have you ever noticed this problem? Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: I am not familiar reactjs but, the condition at `if` is not correct in js. Try `if (usernew==true)..`

Comment: Thanks but nothing change...

Comment: Console usernew. What you see ? And just use `if (usernew)` This mean if usernew is not undefined or null than condition will be true.

Comment: In fact the function shown is that of the inscription, I edited my message to put the good function so the problem does not come from the condition

Comment: Did you create the instance due to provider ?

Comment: Yes it's working with chrome and safari

Comment: Yes, I saw lately :) only thinking that your browser may block the site or (localhost) for pop-up.

Comment: The problem appears in local and online, maybe my browser yes but I don't know how to change that, I tried to disallow AdBlock for this website but doesn't work

Comment: Open the link at Chrome `chrome://settings/content/popups?search=pop`

Comment: add the sites and localhost to allow  pop-up there

Comment: I found the equivalent on firefox but it does not change anything